# How to animate CAGradientLayer color points?

Tags: swift, calayer, cabasicanimation, caanimation, cagradientlayer

I have a problem while animating the CAGradientLayer angle.

Angle in CAGradientLayer is represented through start and end point properties.

I want to animate the gradient in a circular fashion.

When I set it inside an animationGroup it doesn't work. No animation is happening.
When I am changing the properties in

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: now() + 1.0) {
    // change properties here
}
```

it works. But a very fast animation is happening. Which is not good enough.

On the internet the only thing there is is locations and color changes, but no angle change.

Below you can find a Playground project to play with

```
//: A UIKit based Playground for presenting user interface

import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class MyViewController : UIViewController {

    // Gradient layer specification
    lazy var gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer = {
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.5).cgColor, UIColor.orange.withAlphaComponent(0.5).cgColor, UIColor.orange.cgColor]
        gradientLayer.locations = [0, 0.27, 1]
        gradientLayer.frame = view.bounds
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
        return gradientLayer
    }()

    func animationMapFunction(points: [(CGPoint, CGPoint)], keyPath: String) -> [CABasicAnimation] {
        return points.enumerated().map { (arg) -> CABasicAnimation in
            let (offset, element) = arg
            let gradientStartPointAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: keyPath)

            gradientStartPointAnimation.fromValue = element.0
            gradientStartPointAnimation.toValue = element.1
            gradientStartPointAnimation.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + Double(offset)

            return gradientStartPointAnimation
        }
    }

    lazy var gradientAnimation: CAAnimation = {
        let startPointAnimationPoints = [(CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0), CGPoint(x: 1.0, y:0.0)),
                                         (CGPoint(x: 1.0, y:0.0), CGPoint(x: 1.0, y:1.0)),
                                         (CGPoint(x: 1.0, y:1.0), CGPoint(x: 0.0, y:1.0)),
                                         (CGPoint(x: 0.0, y:1.0), CGPoint(x: 0.0, y:0.0))]

        let endPointAnimatiomPoints = [(CGPoint(x: 1.0, y:1.0), CGPoint(x: 0.0, y:1.0)),
                                       (CGPoint(x: 0.0, y:1.0), CGPoint(x: 0.0, y:0.0)),
                                       (CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0), CGPoint(x: 1.0, y:0.0)),
                                       (CGPoint(x: 1.0, y:0.0), CGPoint(x: 1.0, y:1.0))]

        let startPointAnimations = animationMapFunction(points: startPointAnimationPoints, keyPath: "startPoint")
        let endPointAnimations = animationMapFunction(points: startPointAnimationPoints, keyPath: "endPoint")

        let animationGroup = CAAnimationGroup()
        animationGroup.duration = 5.0
        animationGroup.repeatCount = Float.infinity
        animationGroup.animations = startPointAnimations + endPointAnimations

        return animationGroup
    }()

    override func loadView() {
        let view = UIView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        self.view = view

        view.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
    }

    func animate() {
        view.layer.removeAllAnimations()
        gradientLayer.add(gradientAnimation, forKey: nil)
    }
}
// Present the view controller in the Live View window
let vc = MyViewController()
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = vc

vc.animate()
```

Comment: This is more like a math than a Swift question. What you need is to create a method that takes an angle and returns the two CGPoints on opposite directions

Comment: No. The point is, whatever values I put in. Nothing works. Its' like the property is not animatable. The values are right and have nothing to do with "math"

Comment: Thats why I said to animate it manually

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by "animate manually"?

Comment: I think your only option is to use a timer.

Comment: @LeoDabus :D :D :D
Sounds hacky

Comment: Another option is to animate the layer rotation

Comment: How to do that? Rotate the layer itself?

Comment: CABasicAnimation

Comment: The documentation says start and end points are animatable. I think you should try playing with the animation values to get what you want. Try first a 90 degree rotation. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cagradientlayer

Comment: I'm trying to do manual animation with the timer. Need the function mapping angle to points though

Comment: manual animation with timer worked for me. I packed it into CATransaction blocks.
Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what I did was a timer, that triggers start and end points change.

I rotate from 0 to 360 degrees, while incrementing the angle with a given constant (in my case 6)

I created a function mapping: angle → (startPoint, endPoint)

```
func animate() {
    stopAnimation()

    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.05, repeats: true, block: { timer in
        self.angle += 6.0
        self.angle.formTruncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 360)

        CATransaction.begin()
        // disable implicit animation
        CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)

        let pos = points(from: self.angle)

        self.gradientLayer.startPoint = pos.0
        self.gradientLayer.endPoint = pos.1

        CATransaction.commit()
    })
}

func stopAnimation() {
    timer?.invalidate()
}
```

And here are the utility functions

```
extension CGPoint {
    var inverse: CGPoint {
        return CGPoint(x: 1 - x, y: 1 - y)
    }
}

fileprivate func points(from angle: Double) -> (CGPoint, CGPoint) {
    let start: CGPoint

    switch angle {
    case let x where 0 <= x && x < 90:
        start = CGPoint(x: x / 180, y: 0.5 - x / 180)
    case let x where 90 <= x && x < 180:
        start = CGPoint(x: x / 180, y: x / 180 - 0.5)
    case let x where 180 <= x && x < 270:
        start = CGPoint(x: 2.0 - x / 180, y: 0.5 + (x - 180) / 180)
    case let x where 270 <= x && x < 360:
        start = CGPoint(x: 2.0 - x / 180, y: 0.5 + (360 - x) / 180)
    default:
        start = CGPoint.zero
    }

    return (start, start.inverse)
}
```